# Backspace functionality in calculator for ios

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

I want to remove the last digit when pressed a button.

```
int a=12345;
```

When pressed a button, it should leave the value of a=1234.

If pressed second time it should leave the value of a=123 and so on.

I have implemented UILabel to display the input and calculation so it should display 123 on UILabel

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd store the numbers as `NSString`s until the user is done editing. Only at that point should you convert to numbers to do the maths.

Anyway...

```
NSString *string = //get the string from the label or something.

string = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [string length] - 1)];
// or
string = [string substringToIndex:[string length]-1];

//thanks Bhavin

label.text = string;
```

Comment: It's giving the error, "No visible @interface for NSString declares the selector subStringWithRange".

Comment: @user3575678 Always use code completion. I am writing in a web browser, you are writing in an IDE. The second S should be lowercase.

Comment: @Fogmeister, It's working perfectly fine. It removes the last digit but one more question how to change the value of variable. For example how to save the value of a=123. Thanks.

Comment: @user3575678 Like I said in my answer. Store the values as strings not as ints. (Besides, you should really be using NSInteger). Anyway... look up the docs for `NSString`. It has a method `intValue`.